# Understanding the role of a constant in a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was given this problem:

Michaelis–Menten kinetics is a model that describes the rate of enzyme reactions by relating the reaction rate, V, measured in micromolars per minute, to the concentration of a substrate, S, measured in millimolars. The formula is shown above, where Vmaxis the maximum rate of the reaction and K is a constant. Which of the following is the best description of the constant K in this context?

The equation is:

$$V = \frac{V_{max}*S}{K+S}$$

I did not understand how I could obtain the meaning of this constant so I looked at the explanation, which says:

$$S = K$$
$$V = \frac{V_{max}*K}{K+K}$$
$$V = \frac{V_{max}*K}{2K}$$
$$V = \frac{V_{max}}{2}$$

So the answer is

> K is the substrate concentration at which the rate of reaction is equal to $$\frac{1}{2}V_{max}$$

However, I understand the work to get to 1/2Vmax, but I don't understand **how are they able to make the assumption that S = K?**

Comment: They don't.  K is a constant.  S is a variable that can equal various values.  If S has the value of K you get the following result.  Therefore... K is the value so that if S is that value you get the result.  It's be bit like saying:  P = x^2 + 3x + 5.  If x = 0 then P = 5, therefore "5 is the constant that represents the value of P when x = 0".  Putting it in those terms is bass-ackward in mathematical sense.  If P and x have physical significance though this might be a sensible statement.

Comment: @fleablood But when you say x = 0, it has some reason, which is to find the intersection with the x-axis. I don't understand why S = K makes any sense to find the meaning of the constant K. Like if I was taking a test, I would not have thought of setting those two variables equal each other

Comment: Well, me neither.  But we *can*.  And if we do we get the result that setting S to K means half the maximum... well, there it is.